# I can access my apache website via localhost, but other users are being denied access

Tags: windows, windows-10, apache-http-server

I recently set up a website with Apache HTTP web server. My problem is that when I visit http://localhost or http://192.168.1.205 (the local IP address assigned statically to my computer) the website loads just fine. However, when the site is accessed from another device in my LAN such as my iPhone or a device outside of the LAN, a 403 forbidden error is shown. I tried placing a .htaccess file in the root directory of my site (C:\wamp64\www) with the following code.

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
Options +Indexes
```

However, this didn't work. I'm using WAMP Server version 3.1.4 on a 64-bit Windows 10 installation. My Apache version is 2.4.35.

Comment: Have you tried putting these statements into the main config file (instead of a `.htaccess` file)? Often the `.htaccess` file is ignored or restricted.

Comment: Attie yes, I put them right at the end; it took down the whole server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Apache changed its syntax beginning with 2.4. Change

```
allow from all
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

There will be a change for

```
order allow,deny
```

as well but I'm not sure what that is, since I don't know this stuff well. Check [Apache documentation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory)

Comment: Do you know where abouts in the httpd.conf file this needs to go? Putting it right at the end of the file fried the whole server.

Comment: Do you have your "allow from all" etc in a Directory directive? You should substitute the "Require all granted" where your "allow from all" is and that should be inside a Directory, like this:  <Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: Make sure you are not putting "allow from all" where you have the root directory. You don't want to open up everything.

Comment: Terri Simon I'm using windows, not linux as I said in the question. So will I need to replace /var/www with /wamp64/www?

Comment: I haven't done this on Windows (sorry I didn't notice it in your post) but that makes sense. Do you have a Directory directive already there, where your "allow from all" is? Could you maybe give a bigger snippet from your file?

Comment: There are no directory directives contained in the file. I don't know much about directives and such; I'm just starting out with this Apache stuff. Anyway, the code that I included in the post is all the code that is contained within the file; there are no bigger snipits I can provide.

Comment: Oh! Ok, I'm not an expert by any means, but everything I've seen while researching a similar issue has the information that you have placed in side a Directory directive. See the sample in my first comment and take a look at "Directory" in that Apache docs link I gave you. What the directive is doing is tying the permissions that you list to a specific location. I think you really need to do that, otherwise whatever permissions you give are either a) not going to work, or b) work on everything. I'm not sure which, but neither is a good thing.

Comment: I guess it was A: not going to work hahaha. I got my information from htaccess-guide.com which probably wasn't such a good idea since those articles were posted like 11 years ago. I'll try putting it in a directive. But can someone please clarify that my windows equivolent of /var/www (/wamp64/www) is correct? I don't want another server crash.

Comment: If you are using WAMP I think that is correct. I did a quick search and, although this is a different problem, I think the sample code is what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107164/wampserver-3-0-0-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration

Comment: The other thing I noticed is that you originally had your 3 lines in a .htaccess file. If that isn't working, put it in a file called httpd.conf.

Comment: Terri Simon as I already stated, I tried that, but it killed apache so I had to delete the lines to bring the server back online. Maybe right at the bottom of the file was the wrong place to put the lines?

Comment: Did you put the lines inside a <Directory></Directory>? If you don't do that, it isn't going to work. You said that those were the only lines in your .htaccess file, so I don't know what you mean by "bottom of the file." These should be in your httpd.conf file. I don't know about location in the file. It would be easier to tell if you post the whole httpd.conf file.

Comment: Posting the file is ok, but the code has to be oh so correctly formatted for this site. Going through each line and indenting it by 4 spaces will take me hours.

Comment: Problem solved! All I did was put require all granted into the .htaccess file without the order allow,deny statement before it.

Comment: Ah, yeah that makes sense. BTW, even if you can't mark my answer right, could you give it an upvote? Thanks!